# How to map the enclosing content of an XML tag with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to make JAXB to capture the tag's content into some property of Java Bean.
This is an example of XML message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Film Id="5705" Title="Some title" TitleOrig="Original title">
     The description follows
</Film>
```

I've come up with the following Java Bean for this XML message,
but I'm finding difficulties with mapping the film's description.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Film")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Film")
public class Film
{
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    public Integer id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Title")
    public String title;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "TitleOrig")
    public String titleOrig;

    public String description; // How to annotate this property ?
}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction ?
Is this a valid XML ? Cause I failed to find any solutions to this task on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@XmlValue`, i.e.

```
@XmlValue
public String description;
```

Comment: Oh ! I read the description of this annotation but didn't get it. Thanks, it works